# Is it possible to resolve this assembly mismatch situation? Or is this unresolvable?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-assembly, versioning

In my assembly I want to use

`SomeLibrary.dll` -> `Newtonsoft.Json, Version 10.0.0.0`

where I'm referencing `SomeLibrary.dll` by path. Then I also have

`Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` -> `Newtonsoft.Json, Version 9.0.0.1`

where those are both referenced by Nuget. This causes version mismatch when I do

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeTypeFromSomeLibrary>(json)`

Anything I can do about this? :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of issue is usually resolved with a [binding redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions).

For JSON.NET, it might look something like this:

```xml
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```